# How should I store this in DynamoDB if I want to search by these fields?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table that contains the following keys:

`id` (value is a uuid) - this is the primary key

`some_other_field` - is just a regular key

I'd like to be able to query DynamoDB to get the items where `some_other_field` equals some value.

In order to do that, does `some_other_field` need to be a sort key?

Can I instead store this a Document item, instead of a key-value item? I've found no documentation how to do so, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a DynamoDB **table** (not item) with the keys:

- `id` - string - call it Partition Key or Hash Key
- `some_other_field` - string|number|blob - call it Sorting Key or Range key or Regular column if it is not in the key

Whatever your case is, I would define a Global Secondary Index with the Partition Key: `some_other_field` and Projection: `KEYS_ONLY`.

You can query the index for your the items with `some_other_field = VALUE`. Thus, you never scan the whole table, you only get what you need.

---

```
// There may be some small errors in names, consider that code a hint ;)
const params = {
  TableName: 'MY_TABLE_NAME',
  IndexName: 'MY_INDEX_NAME',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#pk': 'some_other_field', // GSI partition key
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':pk': MY_VALUE,
  },
}
```

---

This is not the only solution, you can also scan the table with a filter expression to keep the items that match the condition, but it is more expensive than the solution above because it always scan all the table.